# Xcode 8 - iOS 10.0.2: Error mounting developer disk image

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have the latest **Xcode 8** (no more updates available) on El Capitan, my phone runs **iOS 10.0.2**. [Xcode] > [Devices] lists my iPhone as available - no problems.

I'm getting "**Error mounting developer disk image**" when running a build in Xcode.

I went through through all the threads on stackoverflow related to "Error mounting developer disk image" and they all recommend to get Xcode updated after the iOS upgrade. That has been done, yet I am still facing the same error message. Am I missing something?

Comment: Turn out shutting down your phone and start it over can fix the problem

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that tonight and let you know how it went.

Comment: Restarted the phone - didn't help.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this Folder
Finder > Xcode > Show Package Contents > Developer > Platforms > DeviceSupport.

and here you need to add the dmg(disk image) for ios 10.

Just copy the same folder in that device support folder where you will see many other folders for various ios versions

You can download it from here.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-w5Nhpy8tOwclhFR1JSRjM5YWM/view?usp=sharing

after this just  restart xcode.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked it - I already have `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg` and `DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/10.0 (14A345)/`

Comment: I had the DeviceSupport setup correctly for iOS 10 to begin with.